# Karate UI - while creating new tab I'm getting error messages even though new tab is opened

Tags: automation, ui-automation, karate

I've 1 case where I need to create new tab with new URL & then perform some actions on it.
So for that I tried with following script:

- script("window.open('https://www.w3schools.com', '_blank')")

Now, I can see new tab is opened with given URL but my cases getting failed with following error:

[DEBUG] 2021-11-10 16:03:57.479 [main] c.i.k.d.DriverOptions - >> {"id":10,"method":"Runtime.evaluate","params":{"expression":"window.open('https://www.w3schools.com', '_blank')","returnByValue":true}}
[DEBUG] 2021-11-10 16:03:57.481 [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] c.i.k.d.DriverOptions - << {"method":"Page.windowOpen","params":{"url":"https://www.w3schools.com/","windowName":"_blank","windowFeatures":["menubar","toolbar","status","scrollbars","resizable"],"userGesture":false}}
[DEBUG] 2021-11-10 16:03:57.622 [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] c.i.k.d.DriverOptions - << {"id":10,"error":{"code":-32000,"message":"Object reference chain is too long"}}
[WARN ] 2021-11-10 16:03:57.623 [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] c.i.k.d.DriverOptions - devtools error: [id: 10, error: {code=-32000, message=Object reference chain is too long}]

Comment: devtools error: [id: 10, error: {code=-32000, message=Object reference chain is too long}]

Comment: if still stuck, follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue